# Why it is copying one file only

Tags: linux

It is copying only one file.

```
find ../../ -type f -name <filename.PDF> -print0 | xargs -0 -I file cp -rv file --target-directory=directory name with path
```

why it is copying only one file. I want to copy all file which is having same name but created on different date and different folders.

Comment: You do realize that every copy to target directory will overwrite the the previous file you just copied.

Comment: indeed, as @jimmcnamara says : your `find` will find files of the SAME name. For each one, it will copy it to the same destination directory : this means the 2nd one will overwrite the first one, and then next one overwrite it, etc. So you end up with the last one found by `find` ... You have to rename the files as you copy them. (See Jim solution)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
cnt=1
find ../../ -type f -name filename.PDF | 
while read fname
do
  f=$(basename $fname)
  cp $file /target/directory/${f}.${cnt}
  cnt=$(( $cnt + 1 ))
done
```

give each destination file a unique number.